# Truffle migrate not deploying to ganache

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am trying to deploy my contract to ganache to test my contract but am getting errors.

when I run

> truffle migrate --network development --reset

I receive

> ## Compiling your contracts...
>
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

but when I look at Ganache it says there are no contracts

and when I run truffle test I get

> Error: SimpleStorage has not been deployed to detected network
> (network/artifact mismatch)

my truffle-config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "5337"
    },
  }
};
```

and my migration file

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations)
  deployer.link(Migrations, SimpleStorage)
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage)
} as Truffle.Migration;

export {};
```

honestly, I just want to do write some tests and have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you did not add your current project to ganache.

When you create a new workplace on ganache, you have two options:

[image]

Clic on "Add project" and go to directory of the truffle.config.js. Make sure you choose truffle.config.js

```
    /home/Documents/ethereum/storageProject/truffle-config.js
```

Restart ganache, then migrate your project again and you will see the migrations on ganache under Contracts tab